# how to widen the Visual Studio Code's Terminal window from left end of screen to right end of screen?

Tags: layout, visual-studio-code, terminal

In Visual Studio Code, Terminal window is some inconvenient because of the width.
I want to widen the width from the end of screen to the end of screen.
Is it possible?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxnK9.png)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, no, this isn't possible to some extent, but perhaps there are some extensions you could search around to see if they can do something similar. 
Remember that using your PC's command terminal is also an option.

However, I've found that minimizing the left sidebar by dragging it to the left is an option, which increases the terminal width to the entire screen if this is what you're looking for:

[image: Terminal at screen width]

Note doing that disables you from accessing that entire sidebar unless you drag it out again.